# Qt skips lines when rendering in small zoom levels

Tags: qt, line, rasterizing

I have noticed the following problem when implementing a Word-like application:

The QRasterizer in Qt skips lines when they have a thickness smaller than 1.0f. I am running into this situation when zooming out in my word editor application. The Y values of the two line points then get as small as this:

```
  y1 = 290.32812500000000
  y2 = 290.92187500000000
```

When rendering the line Qt skips it. I have tracked this down to the following code in QRasterizer::rasterize(), where min_y and max_y are the two above Y values times 64 (fixed point values):

```
int iTopBound = qMax(d->clipRect.top(), int((min_y + 32 + COORD_OFFSET - COORD_ROUNDING) >> 6));
int iBottomBound = qMin(d->clipRect.bottom(), int((max_y - 32 + COORD_OFFSET - COORD_ROUNDING) >> 6));

if (iTopBound > iBottomBound)
    return;
```

Since min_y is rounded upwards and max_y is rounded downwards it runs into the IF condition and thus returns without performing any rendering.

I can workaround this problem by enabling anti-aliasing, which however results in the rendering getting brighter when zooming out. What I really need is a behavior like in Microsoft Word: no matter how far you zoom out, a black rectangle always stays visible as black rectangle on screen.

Using a cosmetic pen would solve the problem but doesn't work together with a customizable line thickness, which I need to support as well.

Any ideas how to workaround this problem?

Greetings,

Fabian

Comment: In the end I have added a workaround by rendering the rectangle as single lines instead if using drawRect(). This works correctly for some reason, although it is not a nice solution.